# Send bitmap (.bmp) image to printer in Java

Tags: java, image, printing, bitmap, bmp

Does someone know how to send bitmap image to printer? I have a special printer for recipes which can print ".bmp" format only.. At least this mentioned in manuals.

I tried print as different formats, but always just some hash coming out..

```
import javax.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.*;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterName;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterResolution;

public class PrintService {

private void printImage() {
        try {
            PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            pras.add(new Copies(1));
            PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

            DocPrintJob job = printService.createPrintJob();

            String pathToImageSortBy = "logo.bmp";
            InputStream logoInputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(pathToImageSortBy);

            DocAttributeSet das = new HashDocAttributeSet();
            das.add(new PrinterResolution(203, 203, PrinterResolution.DPI));

            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(logoInputStream, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG, das);
            job.print(doc, pras);
            logoInputStream.close();


        } catch (PrintException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

Or might be someone know about another, third part libraries to do this?

Comment: `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG` doesn't seem right for a BMP?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried all formats in a list, but output line always like "jhHjgHJh23kKkn.."

Comment: Well, BMP is not in the list, so you have to create one yourself. Have you tried `new DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM("image/bmp")`?

Comment: PS: It will probably help your question if you add the model/make of the printer. And links to the documentation that describes the formats it supports.

Comment: Yes, I tried to make a new DocFlavor, but receive "sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid flavor"

Comment: this is Termal Receipt Printer. Model Excelvan ZJ-5890K.
With native driver, provided with printer, we got software, which print image (just bitmap) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After trying things by myself with almost no progress and days searching around, I found a developer on GitHub who already developed a library for ESC/POS commands, with most of functionalities.
So I propose to not reinvent the wheel and use that library.

- [Link to the library](https://github.com/anastaciocintra/escpos-coffee)
- [Link to samples](https://github.com/anastaciocintra/escpos-coffee-samples)
- [Link to Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.anastaciocintra/escpos-coffee)

I tested it printing a bitmap with an Epson TM-T20ii printer and worked well. I hope it fits your needs.